# Managing images in asp.net repeater (add class to each picture)

Tags: asp.net, webforms

This is my code:

Codebehind:

```
public class data
....
...

public List<dataImages> Images { get; set; }
...

var data= GarageBLL.LoadData(Convert.ToInt32(DataId), Convert.ToInt32(MemberId));
rptImages.DataSource = data.Images.Take(3);
rptImages.DataBind();
```

aspx:

```
   <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptImages">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image runat="server" CssClass="img1" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("/images/{0}/{1}.{2}", DataId, Eval("ImageId"), Eval("Extension")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

So, this works at the moment, but **i would like to add different classes to each image**.
Anyone got any idea how i can do that?

Comment: Add classes based on what criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use repeater's [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event to set the `CssClass`:

```
protected void rptImages_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
      // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.
      // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
         dataImages img = (dataImages) e.Item.DataItem;
         Image img1 = (Image) e.Item.FindControl("img1");
         // add your correct logic here according to the dataImages properties
         img.CssClass = "YourCssClass";
         // assuming you just want different classes for your three images, use ItemIndex with remainder:
         string class = "img" + (e.Item.ItemIndex % 3 + 1).ToString() + "class";
         img.CssClass = class;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Alright, but will i be able to have 3 pictures with 3 different classes?  Since i can't add 3 images in the repeater(since that will be 9 pictures), how can each picture get different classes?

Comment: I will probably make img1class, img2class and img3class. As in css classes

Comment: Btw, it doesnt seem possible to add a CssClass to a item inside the repeater. Can't seem to reach it, or?

Comment: Say again? That's exactly what i'm doing above. Have you seen the edits?

Comment: I ended up with this which is working.


           `if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                var img = (Image) e.Item.FindControl("carImage");
                var imgclass = "img" + (e.Item.ItemIndex%3 + 1);
                img.CssClass = imgclass;
            }`

And, thanks alot! This have been annoying for some time!