# How to display the images in a gridview by retriving it's name from the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have stored the name of the image & name of that person in Student table in a database and kept all the images in a folder named UploadedImg now I want to show all the student's name & their images in a gridview in another page. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these links may help you. go through it

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/166_Displaying_Images_in_a_GridView.aspx

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/display-images-gridview-from-database.html

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you know how to DataBind to GridView your GridView will have a code like that (your column names assumed "name" and "image")

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server"
     GridLines="Horizontal">

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# "~/UploadedImg/"+Eval("image") +".jpg"%>' Width="16" />     
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:BoundField DataField='<%#Eval("name") %>'/>
    </Columns>       
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read up on asp.net. Look for the use of a repeater to add `<img>` to your aspx page.

There should be a lot of examples online

Comment: can u plz send me the code or suggest me a link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13211586/532498